# axios and vuex are deleting wrong index in array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

hello i have an problem by laravel and vuejs my problem is that when i try to delete a post from posts in my store file it always delete firs object of array but in database it delete the correct row

here is my store file

```
state:
    {
        posts:[]

    },
getters:
    {
        posts:state=>
        {
            return state.posts
        }
    },
mutations:
    {
        AllPosts:(state,payload)=>{
            state.posts=payload;
        },
        DeletePost:(state,payload)=>{
            state.posts.splice(payload,1);
        }
    },
actions:
    {
        AllPosts:({commit},payload)=>{
            commit("AllPosts",payload)
        },
        DeletePost:({commit},payload)=>{
            commit("DeletePost",payload)
        }
    }
```

and this is my destroy function in postcontroller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post=Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return response()->json($post,200);
    }
```

and this is my axios

```
deletepost(id)
                {
                    axios.delete("/admin/posts/delete/"+id)
                        .then(res=>
                        {
                            this.$store.dispatch("DeletePost",res.data)
                            console.log(res.data)
                        })
                },
```

and this is the html part of code

```
<tr v-for="(post,i) in allposts" :key="post.id">
                <td>{{post.id}}</td>
                <td>{{post.category}}</td>
                <td v-if="post.title.length<30">{{post.title}}</td>
                <td v-else>{{ post.title.substring(0,30)+"..." }}</td>

                <td v-if="post.shortly.length<30">{{post.shortly}}</td>
                <td v-else>{{ post.shortly.substring(0,30)+"..." }}</td>
                <td><img height="100px" width="100px" :title=imagealt(i) :src="image(i)" :alt="imagealt(i)"></td>
                <td>{{post.created_at}}</td>
                <td><button class="delete-btn" @click.prevent="deletepost(post.id)">delete</button></td>
                <td><button class="edit-btn" @click.prevent="editpost(post.id)">edit</button></td>
            </tr>
```

what should i do to delete the correct obeject of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `DeletePost` mutation:

```js
state.posts.splice(payload,1);
```

The first argument for `splice` is an index. You can't just pass it the object you want to remove.

You could write it something like this:

```js
const index = state.posts.findIndex(post => post.id === payload.id);

if (index !== -1) {
    state.posts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Or perhaps use `filter` instead:

```js
state.posts = state.posts.filter(post => post.id !== payload.id);
```

I'd also consider passing the `id` directly to the mutation as the payload rather than passing the whole post object.

Comment: what that mean if index !==-1?

Comment: @erfanahmad If `findIndex` can't find a post that matches the predicate function it will return `-1`, just like `indexOf`. In practice the post *should* always be found in the array but it didn't seem like a safe assumption for that mutation to be making. Calling `splice` with `-1` would cause the last element to be removed, which isn't what we'd want.